# Calling a PHP variable through button onclick

Tags: php, html

The goal is to call the variable $url when the button is clicked. With this current bit of code, when the button is clicked nothing happens and the error says unexpected token.

```
     <?php
        $url = "edit_beginningcakephp.php?title=$title&author=$author&isbn=$isbn
                &year=$year&pages=$pages&price=$price";
            >?

  <input type="button" value="Edit Book" onclick="window.location.href='<?= $url ?>'">
```

Comment: Open generated html and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're not correctly encoding the content of the variables (known as [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting))

You need to [urlencode](https://secure.php.net/manual/de/function.urlencode.php) the content of your variables. Also, `&` needs to be entered as an HTML entity `&amp;`.

Try:

```
$url = 'edit_beginningcakephp.php?title='.urlencode($title).'&amp;author='.urlencode($author).'&amp;isbn='.urlencode($isbn).'&amp;year='.urlencode($year).'&amp;pages='.urlencode($pages).'&amp;price='.urlencode($price);
```

PS: `>?`should be `?>` and make sure the URL doesn't contain any newlines.

Comment: this came up with a parse error.

Comment: using a p tag works with it, which doesn't make sense `<p><a href="<?= $url?>">Edit Book</a></p>`

Comment: The parse error was a comma that should have been a period. MrTux's solution seems to work on my machine, but I have no idea why your own code does nothing.

Comment: after deleting the returns, MrTux's answer was the solution I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

"   >?    "
That looks like it might be a problem, definitely throws a syntax error on my local :)

Comment: That too. There might be even more problems that we don't know about, since we can't see the variables. I mean, what if $year is a DateTime rather than a string.

Comment: " >?" seems to be only a problem in this post as the poster OP doesn't complain about a syntax error in php

Answer (score 0):

While MrTux's answer is very good and his advice should surely be followed, the actual problem with your code is the return in the URL. URLS can't contain returns!
Solution: delete the return. And the spaces. And follow MrTux's advice.